# restify jsonbodyparser on specific route

Tags: node.js, restify

I have a nodejs 0.10.7 application with restify 2.5.0, my application is a simple USER crud with file upload, I want to be able to upload the file via writestream for better control receiving the file, so in that order of ideas, I want to be able to use jsonbody parser for the user crud operations when the data the API receives is on JSON but I dont want to parse json the body for when I receive the file, because what body parser does is read everything in memory and Im getting "big" and great ammount of files.

Oh, also Im getting binary data from the client request.

For what I see I have two options, either remove the bodyparser from the server settings and parse every request manually which will take me to my question of how would I parse the body for the CRUD operations.

Or the other would be to find a way to specify jsonBodyParser in certain routes or under certain controllers, but I would not know how.

So is there another option or are these two options that I have, which would be better, and if it is the first option then how od I parse the req.body so that the crud operations can be done easily?

My uploader function https://gist.github.com/maumercado/6f1f96d23bce888934db

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this questions shows that I quite did not understand how routes work in restify.

What I did was set the restify.bodyParser() as a method to run before the controller in the routes, since the routes take an array of functions or a single function as a parameter.

So like this:

```
// User Routes

server.get('/users', usersController.index);
server.post('/users', restify.bodyParser(), usersController.create);
server.get('/users', usersController.checkUsername);

// Upload Route

server.post('/upload', fileController.upload);
```

With that set up, Im able to run bodyparser, wherever I need instead of running on all the server.

Comment: Especially helpful for multipart-form data, Restify's bodyParser parses both json & multi-part which clashes with packages like multer. In that case route level multipartBodyParser is very useful. thanks